# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI can't map the view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to the JSP + Spring, and I am unable to drive my controller to my view.

I already consulted some topics, but still, I do not see my mistake.
Can someone help me?

Folder Structure:

- Controllers: br.com.maycon.controller
- Views: webapp/WEB-INF/views/

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>upload-videos</display-name>

    <!-- Página Inicial -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declaração dos Controllers -->
    <bean name="/index.jsp" class="br.com.maycon.controller.IndexController" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.maycon" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller (IndexController)

```
package br.com.maycon.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

@Controller
public class IndexController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Teste Index Controller");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("msg", "Olá Mundo, deu certo!");

        return model;
    }

}
```

[image: Directory strutcture]

Comment: Do you receive any error message or a HTTP code error like 404 or 500?

Comment: yes, 404 status error

Comment: Tomcat show: "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/upload-videos/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'"

Comment: I'm trying to access http://localhost:8080/upload-videos/index.jsp

Comment: Do you have a `index.html` file in the root of your web application folder or something similar?

Comment: Please, for the love of everything, upgrade to a newer version of Spring.

Comment: @Sotirios I'm a newbie, forgive-me. What is the new version of spring? I'm using Maven, and my spring dependencie is for 4.0.5 release.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No. I have just index.jsp in /WEB-INF/views

Comment: Ok, create this index.html file (leave it empty, it doesn't matter) in the root folder of your web application. Recompile the project, redeploy it and test it.

Comment: root directory would be webapps?

Comment: Nothing yet, just: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/upload-videos/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: And I cleaned the project.

Comment: My bad, it should be inside a views folder: `<root_folder>`/views/index.html.

Comment: Yes, I trying in all folders of webapps, and nothing still happens.

Comment: And you should access to `http://localhost/upload-videos/view/index.jsp`.

Comment: I inserted a picture with the project structure.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Worked with index.html in the url. But not with index.jsp. Without the /view/ in url, just http://localhost:8080/upload-videos/index.html.

Comment: Ok then, try changing the extension of your file from html to jsp.

Comment: I try, and the 404 still persists.

Comment: And I need to use the controller, because the index.jsp will be a dinamic page.

Comment: Sorry @LuiggiMendoza... I'm just curious

Comment: I guess you need to add `<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>` to your `viewResolver` bean. Check here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html and search for `InternalResourceViewResolver` configuration.

Comment: Nothing. I'll redo my project from the start, he is in the top right. Thank you.